# SQL Server Print, Select, and loop statements

Tags: sql-server, select

I need to create a report that would look like this:

```
Group 1:

    bygpno  amount  date
        1   51567.1 Monday, August 1, 2011

Group 2:

    bygpno  amount  date
    2   11424.54    Thursday, September 1, 2011
    2   4479.4  Saturday, October 1, 2011

Group 3:

    bygpno  amount  date
    3   267.65  Tuesday, November 1, 2011
```

My code currently just does the following:

```
bygpno  amount  date
1   51567.1 Monday, August 1, 2011
2   11424.54    Thursday, September 1, 2011
2   4479.4  Saturday, October 1, 2011
3   267.65  Tuesday, November 1, 2011
```

Please note that, the groups 1, 2, 3 are just examples in real I have like 4827, 282, 2199 so nothing in order. Basically, I need to know how would I display the data of each group separately one underneath the other in one report.

This is the code I have

```
SELECT bygpno, SUM(bycash), Date1
FROM sheet1
GROUP BY bygpno, Date1
ORDER BY bygpno
```

Comment: Can use order by bygpno

Comment: Yes, I got the report correct but the problem, I just want to know how would I reorganize it. Thank you for help. I am posting the code I have.

Comment: This is the sort of thing you would do when formatting the report, rather than in the SQL. Are you using a reporting framework (e.g. Crystal Reports)?